# Use of Eval/Lua operations of RedisClient in ServiceStack?

Tags: redis, servicestack

I have an entity

> public class Book
>
> {
>
> public long Id { get; set; }
>
> public string BookName { get; set; }
>
> public int ISBN { get; set; }
>
> public string Author { get; set; }
>
> }

I want to filter records on the bases of a non-key field *Author* like:

select * from Book where Author = 'Jones'

i dont want to fetch all records by "GetAll" function and then perform filterin gon that list.

I hear about Eval/Lua operations in IRedisClient interface named,

**string GetEvalStr(string body, int numOfArgs, params string[] args);**

**int GetEvalInt(string body, int numOfArgs, params string[] args);**

**List GetEvalMultiData(string body, int numOfArgs, params string[] args);**

But i have no idea how to use these functions in my case.

Can anyone help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eval won't help, you'd still have to fetch all records and loop through them (just in a different language). In your case I'd say there's little choice: you should maintain a set for each author containing their book ids if you need look books up by author.

It does mean the data will be duplicated, but that's the only way to build relationships in a non-relational data store.